# Python: two way de-duplicating

Tags: python, for-loop, duplicates

I have a problem trying to de-dupe two text files.
It should be a fairly easy task, but the situation is as follows:

I have two text files created with the same python script.
Each file contains an X number of lines with the same format, being similar to:

`Keys added,HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Tracing\notepad++_RASAPI32
Keys added,HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Tracing\notepad++_RASMANCS
Keys added,HKLM\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Class\{3A1380F4-708F-49DE-B2EF-04D25EB009D5}
Keys added,HKLM\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Enum\Root\LEGACY_PROCMON23
Keys added,HKLM\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Enum\Root\LEGACY_PROCMON23\0000
Keys added,HKLM\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Enum\Root\LEGACY_PROCMON23\0000\Control
Keys added,HKLM\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\services\PROCMON23`

I know for a fact that text file A has some of the exact same lines as file B but it also has unique lines. File B also has unique lines (and obviously some exact duplicates of lines in file A).

I wish to have my script output 3 textfiles, one for the unique lines in file A, one for the unique lines in file B and one that has the duplicate lines in it.

My script thusfar seems to do half of what I want it to, it picks up some lines that are present in both files and puts them in a text file, but it won't for some others, which I find strange since the formatting of the files being processed is the exact same (since I used another Python script to create them)

The line `Keys added,HKLM\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Enum\Root\LEGACY_PROCMON23` for example, is present in both files but doesn't get recognized.

The line `Keys added,HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Tracing\notepad++_RASAPI32` however, is also present in both files but it IS recognized.

My script now looks like this:

```
import sys

input_1 = open(sys.argv[1]).read().splitlines()
input_2 = open(sys.argv[2]).read().splitlines()
print 'First argument is biggest log'

dupes = open('overeenkomsten.txt', 'a')
onlyTen = open('onlyTen.txt', 'a')
onlySeven = open('onlySeven.txt', 'a')

for line in input_1:
    #print line
    if line in input_2:
        #print 'check'
        dupes.write(line+'\n')
    else:
        #print 'check 2'
        onlyTen.write(line+'\n')

for line in input_2:
    if line not in input_1:
        #print 'check 3'
        onlySeven.write(line+'\n')
    else:
        continue

dupes.close()
onlyTen.close()
onlySeven.close()
```

When answering keep in mind that I would like to have traversed all lines in both files. So if I take one of the files as input_1, I still need to run a for loop through input_2 because I wanna know which lines are in input_2 that are not in input_1.

Thanks in advance

Comment: How large are the files? Can't you just use set operations?

Comment: They vary from a few thousand to 500.000+ lines, if not done with performance in mind it could take a script 10+ mins to run (I tried). You mean the answer Ove provided right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks awfully lot like set logic.
If order is not important then this is a way of doing it:

```
s1 = set( input_1 )
s2 = set( input_2 )

lines_in_both_files = s1.intersection(s2)
lines_in_either = s1.union(s2)

# lines in input_1 not in input_2
l1_n2 = s1 - s2
# lines in input_2 not in input_1
l2_n1 = s2 - s1
```

If order is important, do the above, and then check using "line in myset" before writing.

Comment: Looks simple and promising. The order does not matter greatly, I can always sort afterwards. What is important is that I know which lines are unique to file A, which are unique to file B and which lines are present in both.